# GCM 3.0 - Need clarification about upstream message to devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to understand how works the new Google Cloud Messaging and some things remain a bit blurry for me.

From what I understood, a downstream message is a message sent by the app server through GCM cloud. It can be sent to a specific sender, device group or topic suscribers. 
An upstream message is a message sent by a sender to the app server through the GCM CCS. In this case, it looks like something like that : 
`gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", messageId, data);`

On the official website ([here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#sending_upstream_messages_to_device_group_on_android)), it says we can use upstream messages with devices :
`gcm.send(notificationkey, messageId, data);`

I don't understand well how it works in that case. A message is sent to GCM CCS (upstream) then that one automatically delivers it to the given device group/senders (thus downstream (XMPP message response ?) ?) ?

I'm a bit confused, any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`notification_keys` are used to perform [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications), which is a message sent to multiple devices.

Before you can send messages to a device group, you must create a device group, which returns a `notification_key` and register devices in it.

Once devices are registered, an upstream message sent to CCS with the **to** field set to the `notification_key`, GCM will relay the message to all devices registered in the device group with the corresponding `notification_key`.

This allows the sender to send one message to many devices instead of many messages to many devices.

Hope this helps clear things up.

Comment: It clears a few things. But does that message route to the group from the client or it needs to be received by our own server?